# Gamecube disc issue

Tags: technical-issues, nintendo-gamecube, legend-of-zelda-series

I am having issues with my Gamecube, but I can't figure out what's wrong. It only happens with one disc, the Legend of Zelda collectors edition. I can only play Majoras mask from the disc.

The rest of the games / clips / demo gives me either an error message, a cannot read disc message, stops receiving video on my TV, or causes my Gamecube to reset. I've tried cleaning my Gamecube lens and the disc.

Please check out the link to the video I made of each error I'm getting. If you have seen this before or know of a fix, please let me know!

Comment: Assuming there's no obvious physical damage on the disc, sounds like a bad sector or something.  Unfortunately, I don't think there's anything you can do about that.

Answer (score 2):

While there may not be a way to repair the disc you have, if you have a CD/DVD burner, you could try re-creating the disc.

Using a PC, there is a program called "CleanRip" that can help you make an ISO from your original disc. *(no promises on whether it will be able to recover bad sectors)*

The Legend of Zelda Collector's Edition can be downloaded from Archive.org:
https://archive.org/download/RedumpNintendoGameCubeAmericaPart3

---

*You can also browse ISOs created by others from this site on GitHub: https://r-roms.github.io/*